# aspx vs html performance

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, performance

In my asp.net projects I have some pages that are just html and JavaScript and they are have aspx extension.
Now I want to know is s it a good idea to make them html files (instead aspx)?
Is it influences the performance or not, it's not very important?

Comment: Do you understand what an ASPX page is and how it works?

Comment: Yes, IIS can serve static html faster than it can serve asp.net pages.

Comment: Hey Cody Gray! I think you don't know about serving aspx pages. you just look to the extension but the content is important. OK take it easy and look at the extension. it's great for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just turn on the cache for those pages and they will run faster, maybe in the same way an html does.
But if you are using IIS 6, for sure html will be faster, because IIS 6 will serve html files directly and will go to the whole asp.net architecture for serving it. IIS 7 always go to the asp.net architecture.

Answer (score 1):

**Html** always run faster than aspx, because **aspx** must be processed at server side.

Comment: Technically they both have to be processed.  It's just that the server looks at one (a static file) and attempts to serve that by itself.  The other it hands off the request to another process (in this case .NET runtime).